# How to assign dummy binary variables in PYOMO

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

Suppose I have two real variables: X & Y and two binary variables x & y.

I want to add the following constraint pyomo:

```
when X>0 x--->1 else x-->0
when Y>0 y--->1 else y-->0
and x+y==1
```

My approach was
cons1:
x>=X
cons2:
y>=Y
cons3:
x+y==1

but the above doesn't seem to work and the values of x and y are random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two conditions require big M constraints. You can try something like

`M_x * x >= X`, `M_y * y >= Y`, and `x + y == 1` where M_x and M_y are be constants that you set to values that doesn't unnecessarily bound X and Y. These constraints won't restrict the values of X and Y to 1 and will make x = 1 when X > 0 and y = 1 when Y > 0.